# I want to use a discord members count command in my bot but it gives me an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

This is discord.js v13 membercount command. It does not work for some reason. I asked help in many discord server but they turned a blind eye. If anyone could help it would be amazing.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const {MessageEmbed} = require("discord.js");
const config = require("../../botconfig/config.json")
var ee = require("../../botconfig/embed.json")
const settings = require("../../botconfig/settings.json");
module.exports = {
  name: "membercount", //the command name for execution & for helpcmd [OPTIONAL]
  category: "Information", //the command category for helpcmd [OPTIONAL]
  aliases: [], //the command aliases for helpcmd [OPTIONAL]
  cooldown: 5, //the command cooldown for execution & for helpcmd [OPTIONAL]
  usage: "membercount", //the command usage for helpcmd [OPTIONAL]
  description: "Shows the Amount of Members in DETAIL", //the command description for helpcmd [OPTIONAL]
  memberpermissions: [], //Only allow members with specific Permissions to execute a Commmand [OPTIONAL]
  requiredroles: [], //Only allow specific Users with a Role to execute a Command [OPTIONAL]
  alloweduserids: [], //Only allow specific Users to execute a Command [OPTIONAL]
  minargs: 0, // minimum args for the message, 0 == none [OPTIONAL]
  maxargs: 0, // maximum args for the message, 0 == none [OPTIONAL]
  minplusargs: 0, // minimum args for the message, splitted with "++" , 0 == none [OPTIONAL]
  maxplusargs: 0, // maximum args for the message, splitted with "++" , 0 == none [OPTIONAL]
  argsmissing_message: "", //Message if the user has not enough args / not enough plus args, which will be sent, leave emtpy / dont add, if you wanna use command.usage or the default message! [OPTIONAL]
  argstoomany_message: "", //Message if the user has too many / not enough args / too many plus args, which will be sent, leave emtpy / dont add, if you wanna use command.usage or the default message! [OPTIONAL]
  run: async (client, message, args, plusArgs, cmdUser, text, prefix) => {
    try {
      await message.guild.members.fetch();
        message.reply({embeds: [new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor("Member-Count Information About: " +  message.guild.name, message.guild.iconURL({
          dynamic: true
        }),)
        .setColor(ee.color)
        .addField("❱ Total USERS", " \`" + message.guild.memberCount + "\`", true)
        .addField("❱ Total HUMANS", " \`" + message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size + "\`", true)
        .addField("❱ Total BOTS", " \`" + message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.user.bot).size + "\`", true)
        
        .addField("❱ ONLINE", " \`" + message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status != "offline").size + "\`", true)
        .addField("❱ ONLINE", " \`" + message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot && member.presence.status != "offline").size + "\`", true)
        .addField("❱ ONLINE", " \`" + message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.user.bot && member.presence.status != "offline").size + "\`", true)
        
        .addField("❱ IDLE", " \`" + message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status == "idle").size + "\`", true)
        .addField("❱ IDLE", " \`" + message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot && member.presence.status == "idle").size + "\`", true)
        .addField("❱ IDLE", " \`" + message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.user.bot && member.presence.status == "idle").size + "\`", true)
        
        .addField("❱ DND", " \`" + message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status == "dnd").size + "\`", true)
        .addField("❱ DND", " \`" + message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot && member.presence.status == "dnd").size + "\`", true)
        .addField("❱ DND", " \`" + message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.user.bot && member.presence.status == "dnd").size + "\`", true)
        
        .addField("❱ OFFLINE", ":black_circle:\`" + message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status == "offline").size + "\`", true)
        .addField("❱ OFFLINE", ":black_circle:\`" + message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot && member.presence.status == "offline").size + "\`", true)
        .addField("❱ OFFLINE", ":black_circle:\`" + message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.user.bot && member.presence.status == "offline").size + "\`", true)
        .setTimestamp()
      ]});
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(String(e.stack).bgRed)
      return message.reply({embeds: [new MessageEmbed()
          .setColor(ee.wrongcolor)
          .setFooter(ee.footertext, ee.footericon)
          .setTitle(`❌ ERROR | An error occurred`)
          .setDescription(`\`\`\`${e.message ? String(e.message).substr(0, 2000) : String(e).substr(0, 2000)}\`\`\``)
      ]});
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'status')
    at C:\Users\Lucaq\OneDrive\Desktop\NamiSwan\commands\Information\membercount.js:34:102
    at Map.filter (C:\Users\Lucaq\OneDrive\Desktop\NamiSwan\node_modules\@discordjs\collection\dist\index.js:1:2066)
    at Object.run (C:\Users\Lucaq\OneDrive\Desktop\NamiSwan\commands\Information\membercount.js:34:69)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

I am supposed to add some more detail. you dont need to read this it just keeps asking me to add more and more detail.

I am supposed to add some more detail. you dont need to read this it just keeps asking me to add more and more detail.

Comment: `member.presence` is null. Figure out why.

Comment: @ceejayoz the problem is  i dont know why that the reason i am asking

Comment: @ceejayoz cause nothing is defining i think

Comment: `Member#presence` returns `null` for **offline** members. Check for `member.presence === null`

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This code was written for Discord.js v13.3.1*

---

### Filtering null values

As pointed out by [@ceejayoz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1902010), `Member#presence` is undefined. This occurs when users are offline because if you're offline, you don't have an active status. Your Presence is null. (Adapted from [@Elitezen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12464931)'s comment). One simple solution to this is to filter the lists you are fetching by removing any members whose Presence is null. It would look something like this:

```js
<GuildMemberManager>.cache.filter(m => m.presence != null)
```

Now, I've put the GuildMemberManager in <>. This means that you'd replace that with whatever your GuildMemberManager is. For your use, you would replace it with

```js
message.guild.members
```

However, you can simply this statement.

### Multiple Uses

I've also noticed that you're repeating the same lines over and over with similar code. The part that I'm referring to is the GuildMemberManager. You can simply the code by declaring a variable at the beginning and reusing it whenever you need a GuildMemberManager, you can reference that variable. This is one example of what you could do. You have to use await as this function is Promise based.

```js
const manager = await message.guild.members.fetch()
```

Additionally, at the top of the code, you utilize the require function twice to import two Objects. You import the entire `Discord` object then import the `MessageEmbed` object. This can easily be reduced by removing the first line.

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require(`discord.js`)
```

And on line 25, you would update the code from `Discord.MessageEmbed` to `MessageEmbed`. You can also simply more code by using `.addFields(...)` instead of repeatedly running `.addField(...)` over and over again.

### Resulting code

In the end, with all of the changes I have shown here, this is what your new code would look like. **Important!** You must place the manager constructor BEFORE it is called and when it has access to the `message` variable. A good line for this could be line 23 after the run function is defined.

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require(`discord.js`);
// ...
const manager = await message.guild.members.fetch()
.addFields(
  { name: `❱ Total USERS`, value: ` \`${message.guild.memberCount}\``, inline: true },
  { name: `❱ Total HUMANS`, value: ` \`${manager.filter(m => !m.user.bot).size}\``, inline: true },
  { name: `❱ Total BOTS`, value: ` \`${manager.filter(m => m.user.bot).size}\``, inline: true },
  { name: `❱ ONLINE`, value: ` \`${manager.filter(m => m.presence != null).size}\``, inline: true },
  { name: `❱ ONLINE`, value: ` \`${manager.filter(m => m.presence != null && !m.user.bot).size}\``, inline: true },
  { name: `❱ ONLINE`, value: ` \`${manager.filter(m => m.presence != null && m.user.bot).size}\``, inline: true },
  { name: `❱ IDLE`, value: ` \`${manager.filter(m => m.presence != null && m.presence.status === `idle`).size}\``, inline: true },
  { name: `❱ IDLE`, value: ` \`${manager.filter(m => m.presence != null && m.presence.status === `idle` && !m.user.bot).size}\``, inline: true },
  { name: `❱ IDLE`, value: ` \`${manager.filter(m => m.presence != null && m.presence.status === `idle` && m.user.bot).size}\``, inline: true },
  { name: `❱ DND`, value: ` \`${manager.filter(m => m.presence != null && m.presence.status === `dnd`).size}\``, inline: true },
  { name: `❱ DND`, value: ` \`${manager.filter(m => m.presence != null && m.presence.status === `dnd` && !m.user.bot).size}\``, inline: true },
  { name: `❱ DND`, value: ` \`${manager.filter(m => m.presence != null && m.presence.status === `dnd` && m.user.bot).size}\``, inline: true },
  { name: `❱ OFFLINE`, value: `:black_circle: \`${manager.filter(m => m.presence === null).size}\``, inline: true },
  { name: `❱ OFFLINE`, value: `:black_circle: \`${manager.filter(m => m.presence === null && !m.user.bot).size}\``, inline: true },
  { name: `❱ OFFLINE`, value: `:black_circle: \`${manager.filter(m => m.presence === null && m.user.bot).size}\``, inline: true }
)
```

Comment: im having an issue. I seem to have done all the steps you told me to do but on the total humans row and the total bots row it is saying object map and now everyone shows up as offline.

I put the code in source bin so it does not go over the limit
https://sourceb.in/bEwp5A4Ayq

Comment: I've edited this to fix the issues you've highlighted. `manager` now fetches the member list and that should fix the issue of everyone showing as offline.